# Role name Admin is already taken when create a new tenant in ABP Angular

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I have used the Angular 2 + Asp.net Core template which downloaded at 2018/05/23.

What I have done:

1. Change DB from SqlServer to MySql
2. Updated the seed for updating the initialize admin name to "HostAdmin" and "TenantAdmin"
3. Create tenant in admin
4. Got error "Role name TenantAdmin is already taken."
   [image]

I have investigated the code of create tenant, the error happened on CreateStaticRoles during create tenant.

[image]

In this method, it will create new role, but there are duplicate check here. I'm not sure why? and where get the data of  RoleManagementConfig.StaticRoles? I cannot find any value assignment reference in the ABP source code for StaticRoles except UT.

**Edited:**
Added the duplication check logic of Abp, it looks like that the it always cannot pass the check as the static role name/display name already be used by default tenant.
[image]

Comment: Static roles are added in [AppRoleConfig.cs](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/b5c18c989fa236d768d3ec6662edb5d66b4612c3/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Core/Authorization/Roles/AppRoleConfig.cs).

Comment: thanks @aaron, one more question, why Abp create the static roles again when create a new tenant since the tenant static roles already be taken.

Comment: Each tenant has its own roles, including static ones.

Comment: it looks like that it always cannot pass the role name duplication check as the static role name/display name already be used by default tenant. Did I missed some point?

Comment: There's a tenant filter.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose "Include login, register, user, role and tenant management pages" while downloading your startup template, there will be some migration files included in your project. These files are generated for SQL Server. Delete all the migration files in your .EntityFramework project under the Migrations folder. Migration files start with a timestamp. A migration file name should look like this

"201506210746108_AbpZero_Initial" After deleting all the migration files, select your .Web project as the startup project, open Visual Studio's Package Manager Console and select the .EntityFramework project as the default project in the Package Manager Console. Then run the following command to add a migration for MySql.

```
Add-Migration "AbpZero_Initial"
```

Now you can create your database using the following command

```
Update-Database
```

You can now run your project with MySql.